# call google vision Api from Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, google-vision

I want to make a Flutter app where I detect text and number from an image using Google Cloud vision API.

I see the API of Google Cloud Vision is [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision_text_detection-drest).

I know that from Flutter, I need to create a json file, with content is an image.
Then, sending that json file to Google Cloud vision endpoint, and get the result back.

However, how can I implement it in Flutter. Is there any example using this.

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://pub.dev/packages/google_vision

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I did not know that. One following up question: Im not sure if you know this, but the credential file that the library requires is the json we download when creating Service Account?

Comment: There is some error using above library. Do you have another  suggestions? Thanks very much.